# This Line Breaks my application because of unhandled exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

This Line Breaks my application because of unhanded exception.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var responseMessage =await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:63650/api/student");

//HttpContent content = responseMessage.Content;
//var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();


var RestUrl = "http://localhost:63650/api/student";
var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, string.Empty));

var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
   var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(content);
   }
```

Comment: Add a try catch and figure out which exception exactly that is not being handled and handle it.

Comment: At which line did you get this exception and what is the info of your exception?

Comment: Which line is "this" line and what is the exception?